# error installing SASS JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data

Tags: node.js, json, npm, sass

It's my first time of using SASS and I cannot understand what am I doing wrong? I've installed SASS, and I'm trying to `npm run style` but there's an error.

Terminal says that
`MacBook-Pro-Anastasia:live coding anastasia$ npm run style
npm ERR! file /Users/anastasia/Desktop/live coding/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token s in JSON at position 138 while parsing near '...ts": {
npm ERR! JSON.parse     "style": sass sass/style.scss...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.`

Can anyone see what's wrong with the JSON file?

````
 {
  "name": "live-coding",

  "version": "1.0.0",

  "description": "Productly web-page",

  "main": "index.js",


  "scripts": {
    **"style": sass sass/style.scss sass/style.css,**

    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },

  "author": "priuet",

  "license": "ISC"

}```
````

Comment: remove the last 3 single quote  (last line ) from your package.json  file and try to run

Comment: thank you. I've found out that my mistake was the absense of " " for the "Style" line